# Moved mp3's from internal storage to sdcard with su privileges - music apps don't see them now

Tags: cyanogenmod, permissions, files, terminal, superuser

In order to free up space on internal storage I opened a terminal and su removed some uneeded files.  While still su root, I also moved my mp3 collection out of internal storage onto the external sdcard.

When I go back to Terminal, the files still show in `/storage/sdcard1/`, but my music player no longer sees them.

Is this a permissions issue? If so how do I relax permissions so that my music apps can see and open the files?

Comment: Have you already restarted the device? Background: the [media-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) needs to run to update the internal database. See the linked tag-wiki for details, including alternatives to a reboot.

Comment: Most music players I know of only look in directories with specific names.  /storage/sdcard1/ may not be one of them.  Have you checked that the directory has the same name on the SD card that it had on the internal memory?

Comment: @Chenmunka Both Eleven and Apollo are able to see music files from anywhere in the device, provided that the directory where they reside doesn't have a **.nomedia** file inside.

Comment: I've rebooted twice, still no luck.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman do you mean JoeApollo? I installed but there isn't a way to specify external storage.  None of the files on my external storage are seen.